# Changing IP Addresses of an Always On Availability Group in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups

We have two nodes in an Always On availability group, on SQL Server 2014 Enterprise.

We need to change the IP addresses of the nodes, the cluster, and the listener.

They will still remain in the same domain.

The subnet mask shall remain the same.

All will the be the same except the IP Addresses and the default gateway.

What are the steps to accomplish this?

Comment: [This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/146620/alwayson-availability-groups-ip-address-subnet-change-of-secondary-replica-n) ,  [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/145725/alwayson-availability-groups-ip-address-change-of-secondary-replica-node) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/change-the-ip-address-of-a-failover-cluster-instance) will help.

Comment: Sorry my 3rd link is not relevant and I cannot edit a comment after certain time.  You rather consult [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb734866.aspx) link.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following steps to change IP address of the listener

```
ALTER ENDPOINT [MyEndpoint]
      STATE = STARTED
      AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5023, LISTENER_IP = (10.x.x.x))
      FOR DATA_MIRRORING (ROLE = ALL, AUTHENTICATION = Windows Negotiate, 
                          ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES)
GO
```

http://www.ryanjadams.com/2016/01/change-availability-group-endpoint-ip/#axzz4yzaoZP8L

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/change-the-ip-address-of-a-failover-cluster-instance